# Populate and display an html table based on the values from two dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two cascading dropdown boxes controlled with JQuery and Ajax objects. The first determines the values in the second. Then, once a selection is made in the second, the values from the two dropdowns would be used to find a record in an SQL table and display the record in an html table.

So far the dropdowns work correctly but I'm having difficulty getting the record from the database and then displaying it on screen. I've done this before by getting the database values, sending them to the view in a Json object, and using an Ajax object to to create the table with Jquery. However, in this case I don't mind if the page reloads and would like to use a simpler method.

What is a simple method of sending two values from two dropdowns to the controller, using those values to find a record in an sql table, sending the values from the record back to the view to be displayed? Also, I don't want anything to be displayed until the second dropdown box has a selection made.

Here is what I have so far:

Controller methods:

```
List<Car> GetCars()
{
    using (var service = new Service())
    {
        return service.GetCars().OrderBy(x => x.CarName).Select(x => new Car
        {
            CarId = x.CarId,
            CarName = x.CarName
        }).ToList();
    }
}

List<Color> GetColors(int carId)
{
    using (var service = new Services())
    {
        return service.GetColors(carId).OrderBy(x => x.ColorName).Select(x => new Color
        {
            ColorId = x.ColorId,
            ColorName = x.ColorName
        }).ToList();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CurrentSaus(int townCode, int fiscalYear)
{
    var colors = GetColors(carId);

    return Json(new SelectList(colors, "ColorId", "ColorName"));
}
```

Jquery methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Car_CarId").change(function () {
        var carId = $(this).val();
        var carName = $(":selected", this).text();            

        // put the car name into a hidden field to be sent to the controller
        document.getElementById("Car_CarName").value = carName;

        getColors(carId);
    })
});

function getColors(carId) {
    if (carCode == "") {                     
        $("#Color_ColorId").empty().append('<option value="">-- select color --</option>');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Colors", "HotWheels")",
            data: { colorId: clrId },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var colors = "";
            var numberOfColors = data.length;
            if (numberOfColors > 1) {                    
                colors += '<option value="">-- select color --</option>';
            }
            else {
                var colorId = data[0].Value;
                var colorName = data[0].Text;
                document.getElementById("Color_ColorName").value = colorName;
            }

            $.each(data, function (i, color) {
                colors += '<option value="' + color.Value + '">' + color.Text + '</option>';
            });

            $("#Color_ColorId").empty().append(colors);
        }
    });
}
```

and some of the html:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Car.CarName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Color.ColorName)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Select Car:</td>
            <td style="text-align:left">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            x => x.Car.CarId,
                            new SelectList(Model.CarList, "CarId", "CarName"),
                            "-- select town --")
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Car.CarId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Select Color:</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            x => x.Color.ColorId,
                            new SelectList(Model.ColorList, "ColorId", "ColorName"),
                            "-- select color --")
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Color.ColorId)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? I took my time writing this question out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to use an old fashion FORM element and POST the values of the two drop downs to an action in your controller. That action would expect a carId and a colorId and use them to retrieve a record from the DB and then pass the result to your 'view' where you would take care of render/display the result.

Of course using this method has some caveats:

- The entire page will refresh after a user selects a value from the
  second drop down.
- You would have to POST the form using JavaScript
  when the user picks the second option, or at least enable a button so
  the form can be POSTed.
- You would have to keep track of the carId and
  colorId in your controller and view

Another option is to use AJAX to POST (send to the server) the carId and colorId where and action in a controller will take care of using those parameters to find a record in the DB and then return a JSON object with the result. The response will be handled by a 'success' handler where you will take care parsing the JSON object and add rows to a table.

So if you feel more comfortable working on the server side of the code pick the first option, however if you prefer to use AJAX and do this in the front end use the later.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. I guess I'll have to weigh the options a bit.

Comment: With the first option, how would I display the record only after the second dropdown is selected? It will be displayed in an html table, but I only want to see the table after the second dropdown selection.

Comment: I can think of tow options: 1) you have add a handler on the second drop-down for the on-change event, where you submit the form if a value has been selected. 2) You provide a submit button that is enabled only if the second drop-down has a value, this can be also done using a handler on the submit event of the form.

Comment: I know I need to submit the form but what sort of method would I use in the controller...ActionResult? Maybe a partial view?

Comment: You would have to use an action that takes the two parameters, corId and colorId, or either create a new one. The action will use those parameters to perform a search in the DB. How you perform the search depends on how your app interacts with the DB or data service.

Comment: Yes and it would return the view. Then, I guess i would need some kind of switch to turn the table on when the record was sent back? Maybe keep the table hidden somehow until postback?

Comment: If you go for the first option the rendering of the view would happen on the server side, so at that point while rendering the results you could check if you have results and show the table otherwise you hide the table, this is easily done by using a css class or style on the table, for example if you have results apply visibility:hidden otherwise apply visibility:visible to the table

Comment: That's what I was fishing for. Thank you.